# Gson to parse generic type, when type is known from json

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, gson

I have jsons that contain a message of any type and the json contains a String that says which type the message has.

I want to deserialize them and get 1. an Instance of the messag type representing the message and 2. an instance of Topic where T is the message type.

As examples:

**input1**

```
{
"messageType":"String",
"message": "a string"
}
```

I expect a result after the deserialization to be the same as this done by hand:

```
Topic<String> t = new Topic<String>(String.class);
String message = "a string";
```

---

**input2**

```
{
"messageType":"Integer",
"message": 1
}
```

I expect a result after the deserialization to be the same as this done by hand:

```
Topic<Integer> t = new Topic<Integer>(Integer.class);
Integer message = 1;
```

---

**input3**

```
{
"messageType":"MyClass",
"message": {"a": "something", "b": 1}
}
```

I expect a result after the deserialization to be the same as this done by hand:

```
Topic<MyClass> t = new Topic<MyClass>(MyClass.class);
MyClass message = new MyClass("something", 1);
```

---

**input4**

```
... same with other types ...
```

I think you got the point. But now I need to do this somehow in a generic/abstract way. I tried this, but this will not work:

```java
private enum MessageType {
  STRING(String.class), INTEGER(Integer.class), BOOLEAN(Boolean.class), MYCLASS(MyClass.class);
  private Class<?> clazz;
  MessageType(Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }
}


private static class MyJson {
  String topicId;
  String messageType;
  Object message;
}


MyJson<?> myJson = gson.fromJson(input, MyJson.class);
MessageType type = MessageType.valueOf(myJson.messageType);
Class<?> clazz = type.getClass();

??? message = clazz.newInstance(message);
Topic<???> t = new ?????
```

I don't know what to do?! I need Topic and Message typed, but how??? The following seems so bad:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> Topic<T> createTopic(Class<T> typeClass) {
  try {
    return Topic.class.getConstructor(typeClass).newInstance(typeClass);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException("Fail");
  }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what you do.  Generics are a compile time feature in Java, they do absolutely nothing for you when you're trying to figure out a type from a string that arrives at runtime.  Libraries that make it look like they can are just doing the same unsafe things under the hood that you have arrived at.

Comment: yes but how can I do it now? my method does not work

Comment: I need the message type but how do I get it?

Comment: If all the *possible* values are known at compile time you could create TypeTokens and have GSON de-serialize the content of "message" using a type token then set it on your topic.

Comment: Affe, but then I still need to match the messageType to the typetoken. Or is it possible that gson guesses it on its own then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works for me now:

```java
class Topic<MessageType> {
    // ...
    public Class<MessageType> getMessageTypeClass() // ...
    // ...
}
```

parse result data struct:

```
public class TopicLine {
  public Topic<?> topic;
  public Object message;
}
```

deserializer:

```
public class MessageDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<TopicLine> {
  private static class InternalParseLine {
    String messageType;
    JsonElement message;
  }

  private Map<String, Topic<?>> messageTypes = new HashMap<String, Topic<?>>();

  public MessageDeserializer() {
    messageTypes.put("Integer", new Topic<Integer>(Integer.class));
    // other topics
  }

  private static class InternalParseLine {
    String topicId;
    JsonElement message;
  }

  @Override
  public TopicLine deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    InternalParseLine line = context.deserialize(json, InternalParseLine.class);

    TopicLine topicLine = new TopicLine();
    topicLine.topic = topics.get(line.messageType);
    topicLine.message = context.deserialize(line.message, topicLine.topic.getMessageTypeClass());
    return topicLine;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
json = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(TopicLine.class, new TopicLineDeserializer())
    .create();
TopicLine t = json.fromJson(line, TopicLine.class);
```

In fact, to make it more dynamic I use a topics-manager which I pass to the deserializer in its constructor instead of a static map. So I can register and unregister topic/message-types on the fly during runtime.